# PDE method of characteristics solving $e^{t^2}u_t+tu_x=0$ with $u(x,0)=x+2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The equation is given as:

$$e^{t^2}u_t+tu_x=0$$ with $u(x,0)=x+2$

I've got $x=\frac{1}{2}e^{t^2}+x_0$ but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: I added $\LaTeX$ to your question. Please verify it's correct.

Comment: yes this is correct

Answer (score 1):

As you have done, the best way to solve the equation is to write it as
$$
t e^{-t^2} u_x + u_t = 0
$$

Let $u = u\big(x(\eta),t(\eta)\big)$, then

$$
\frac{d}{d \eta} u\big(x(\eta),t(\eta)\big) = u_x x' + u_t t' = 0
$$

means that

$$
t'(\eta) = 1, \qquad x'(\eta) = t e^{-t^2}, \qquad u'(\eta) = 0
$$

**EDIT**

The initial condition is given in the curve $t = 0$, this means we have $t(\eta=0) = 0$.

Now,

$$
t'(\eta) = 1, \quad t(0) = 0 \,\Longrightarrow \,t(\eta) = \eta.
$$

Using this, we have for $x$

$$
\frac{d x}{d \eta} = \eta e^{-\eta^2},
$$
and then
$$
\int_0^\eta \frac{d x}{d \xi} d\xi = \int_0^\eta \xi e^{-\xi^2} d\xi \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x(\eta) - x(\eta = 0) = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{-\eta^2}\right)
$$

or

$$
x(\eta = 0) = x - \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{-t^2}\right).
$$

Finally

$$
\frac{d u}{d \eta} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad u(\eta) - u(\eta = 0) = 0
$$

or

$$
u(\eta) = u(\eta = 0) = x(\eta = 0) + 2
$$

We now conclude that

$$
u(x,t) = x + 2 - \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{-t^2}\right).
$$

Comment: Im a bit confused on how you got the x term. I thought the integral of the te^(-t^2) was just e^-t^2/2. where did the 1 come from?

Comment: also when do we incorporate the fact that when t is 0 x is x+2?

Comment: @user61933 I've edited the answer in order to address your questions. Please, if you find it appropriate, vote up and accept the answer.